# VS2010 Express recommends optimizations in debug mode, and fails running the app without them

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-optimization

we have encountered a very weird behaviour of VS2010 Express C++ recently.

Our app which worked flawlessy, suddenly showed unexpected behaviour in debugmode, like somehow rendering to the full screen, despite it being a smallish editor-window.

What we found out was that the new behaviour can be disabled by switching the code-optimizations in the debugmode from "deactivated" (/Od) to "project default" which then, unexpectedly uses the "maximize speed" option (/O2).

This wouldn't be bad in particular if it weren't that debugging now is almost impossible because of the code restructuring going on, so breakpoints, stepping through it, looking at values, is just meaningless. The debugger cant even figure out the correct values of variables anymore (which is just logical).

So i'm pretty baffled what to do with it. Why does it fail in the first place, and why does it want an optimized program in the debugmode?

Also, not being funny, we encountered a c++ compiler bug, where NOT handing over a template parameter was not noticed by the compiler and so made some code silently fail.

Comment: You're gonna have to provide more information than this. When code behaves differently with different optimizations levels, it usually indicates undefined behavior of some sort. That said, bugs in the compiler are not unheard of, but rare nonetheless.

Comment: I might want to add that we dont use anything like #ifdef DEBUG sort of things. I can also assure you that the program worked fine over months. So i want to know what could make VS want opt. to be turned on, because this cant be a good thing (having opt. turned on in debugmode). Sorry, i am unsure what else to provide

Comment: Sorry, didnt get the undefined behaviour hint. I can say that the app is too large to be easily scanned for hidden details like this.

Comment: If you don't know what "Undefined Behavior" is, you should probably look that up. Searching for such a bug in a large project is not an easy task. So good luck with that.

Comment: I know about it, i just didnt realize what you wrote. Please keep in mind that i want to know why VS things optimized code is good for debugmode, as it doesnt request this for all libraries we build and the app is depending on.

Answer (score 0):

The project defaults are not debug mode defaults, but are actually the defaults for release mode. The project defaults do not know about debug/release configurations. The override /Od is the default setting for debug configurations. If you have reset all project properties in the debug configuration to the defaults, then you have set your debug configuration to pretty much the same as release mode.

There is nothing special about the debug/release configurations - they are just names, so the project properties does not include special defaults for each one.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Afterall, i managed to find out that activating /ZI (edit and resume) in favor of /Zi also makes the application work in debugmode while using /Od (no optimizations turned on).

I'm still baffled. This can't be true. Edit and resume shouldnt affect the basic code, it should just add code to let users edit code on the fly while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Think of stuff like return value optimization. Also look for temporary objects that the compiler avoids creating when code optimization is turned on. Maybe you could use some [C++ lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632057/c-c-free-alternative-to-lint) application to smoke out some of the reasons your code is misbehaving in debug mode.

Comment: Forgot to mention, we already used cppcheck, which didnt find any problems really. We already used it months ago. I'll try and re-run it on our new libraries we now depend on. Thanks a lot.